# How to check the version of Docker used on DockerHub for automated builds?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/kaust-vislab/tensorflow-gpu-data-science-project/blob/build-horovod-with-nccl/docker/Dockerfile) that uses the `COPY --chown $UID:$GID` syntax. I can use Docker to build images from this `Dockerfile` without issue on my MacBook and Linux workstation both of which are running Docker version 19.03.5. However my automated builds on DockerHub fail with the following error.

```
Step 16/26 : COPY --chown=$UID:$GID environment.yml requirements.txt postBuild ./
unable to convert uid/gid chown string to host mapping: can't find uid for user $UID: no such user: $UID
build hook failed! (1)
```

I was surprised by this failure as I assumed that DockerHub would be using a recent version of Docker for automated builds.

How can I check the version of Docker used by DockerHub? Even better would be if I could specify the version of Docker that DockerHub should use in my build hook.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the variables `$UID` and `$GID` are not set in their environment.
In that case you should use the id `1000` like this:

`COPY --chown=1000:1000 environment.yml requirements.txt postBuild ./`

Comment: I create a non-root user with $UID and $GID which can be either set by the image builder or take default values. Default values for these variables are set in the `Dockerfile` but are not being substituted properly in the version of Docker used on DockerHub.